# E4 Databinding for SWT List

Tags: java, data-binding, eclipse-rcp

I try to bind the items of a SWT [List](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FList.html) to a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)< String> property via Databinding.

My model class:

```
public class Config extends ModelObject {
    private List<String> tagList;

    public List<String> getTagList() {
        return tagList;
    }

    public void setTagList(List<String> tagList) {
        firePropertyChange("tagList", this.tagList, this.tagList = tagList);
    }
}
```

My Binding:

```
...
private List tagList;
...
private void addDataBinding() {
    Config config = ConfigHandler.getInstance().getConfig();

    DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();

    IObservableList observableModelTagList = BeanProperties.list(Config.class, "tagList").observe(config);
    IObservableList observableWidgetTagList = WidgetProperties.items().observe(tagList);


    ctx.bindList(observableWidgetTagList, observableModelTagList);
}
```

As it didn´t work out that way, I tried to use [Converters](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fdatabinding%2Fconversion%2FIConverter.html). 
It doesn´t work either but at least I could see that if I use [tagList.add(x)](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FList.html) or [tagList.setItems(x)](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FList.html) on the [tagList](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FList.html) Widget nothing is triggered (the convert method isn´t even called). 
So I guess [WidgetProperties.items()](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdatabinding%2Fswt%2FWidgetProperties.html) doesn´t work as I expect it to. 
I expected it to fire a change everytime anything regarding the items changes so at adding, removal and on a new set.
How do I bind the SWT List to the List Property in my model?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ListViewer` rather than just `List`:

```
ListViewer viewer = new ListViewer(tagList);

IValueProperty displayValue = ... property to display in the list

ViewerSupport.bind(viewer, observableModelTagList, displayValue);
```

Without a 'displayValue' you could use:

```
ListViewer viewer = new ListViewer(tagList);

ObservableListContentProvider contentProvider = new ObservableListContentProvider();
viewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);

viewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());

viewer.setInput(observableModelTagList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Could you explain the IValueProperty field to me a little more?

Comment: or to be more precise: As I use a List<String> doesn´t I have to use BeanProperties.value(String.class, "value"); as IValueProperty? That doesn´t work.

Comment: Added alternative for when you don't have a display value

Comment: Thanks! That kind of works, but only for the initial binding. 
If I start the Application the values from the Model are adopted by the ListViewer but if I change the model or the List Viewer afterwards, the respective other value doesn´t change.

Comment: Sorry, thats about as far as I can go. I abandoned data binding for lists as it doesn't work well with the CSS styling I wanted to use.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your effort! I think I will go for manual listeners then.